# Thread continues to print RAM Usage even after interrupt in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, runtime, monitoring

I'm working on a Java program for a school project where I'm monitoring various system resources using separate threads. However, I'm facing an issue with the `RAMMonitor` thread. Even after calling the `interrupt()` method and waiting for the thread to join, it continues to print RAM Usage indefinitely.

--- Main code ---

```java
public class MonitoringResources {
    // Initialize Monitors and Threads //
    private final RAMMonitor monitor_RAM = new RAMMonitor();
    private Thread thread_RAM = new Thread(monitor_RAM);

    public MonitoringResources() {}  // Constructor
    
    public void startMonitoring() {  // Start methods
        thread_RAM.start();
    }
    
    public void interruptMonitoring() {  // Interrupt
        thread_RAM.interrupt();
        
        try {  // Wait for the RAM thread to stop
            thread_RAM.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MonitoringResources mr = new MonitoringResources();
        mr.startMonitoring();       // Start monitoring
        
        // Monitoring for 10 seconds //
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        
        mr.interruptMonitoring();   // Monitor interrupt
        
        System.out.println("Monitoring terminated.");
    }
}
```

--- RAMMonitor ---

```java
public class RAMMonitor implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            long usedMemory = getUsedMemory();
            long totalMemory = getTotalMemory();
            double memoryUsage = (double) usedMemory / totalMemory * 100;

            System.out.println("RAM Usage -----> " + (int) memoryUsage + "%");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Monitoring per second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { // Sleep Exception
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    private long getUsedMemory() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        return runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    }
    private long getTotalMemory() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        return runtime.totalMemory();
    }
    public void interrupt() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

I'm using the `interrupt()` method to stop the thread and waiting for it to join before ending the program. However, the RAM monitor thread seems to persist even after the `interrupt()` call. What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure that the thread stops as expected?

I have attempted to modify the main method by moving the join() calls outside of interruptMonitoring(), but the issue persists, and the RAM Usage continues to be repeated indefinitely.

Comment: Method `interrupt()` in class `RAMMonitor` is never called. If we change the `while`-condition of method `run()` in `RAMMonitor` to `!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`, it works as expected. [`Ideone.com` demo](https://ideone.com/Fkp6bS)

Comment: `thread_RAM.interrupt();` is calling `interrupt()` of the `Thread`, not of `RAMMonitor` - so it is just interrupting the thread (mostly the `sleep()`) and not resetting the flag - maybe a different method name would be better to avoid such confusion

Comment: Personally, I'd get rid of the `interrupt` in `RAMMonitor` (may, as suggested call it `stopRunning` or something instead) and instead, when `InterruptedException` is triggered, set the flag to `false` in the `catch` clause and/or look at the `isInterrupted` state for the `Thread.currentThread()` after each cycle of the monitor